# Network I/O utilization per process/thread in Linux

Tags: linux, io, pid

We are looking for an utility that allows us to understand which Linux thread (tid/lwp - thread id / light weight process) generates network traffic.

There are such utilities for disk I/O:
iotop
pidstat
They can produce I/O reports detailed by PID and TID.

What utility may produce similar output for network I/O?
We tried nethogs but it gives only PID not TID.

Comment: Take a look at my answer at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183217/lsof-measure-i-o-rate-of-a-socket-fd/183229#183229

Answer (score 2):

Atop tool gives full solution:

http://www.atoptool.nl/downloadatop.php

Download and build both atop and netatop module.
You'll need to install the following libs:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
```

When running

```
sudo atop -n
```

you'll get the screen as attached.

Note that atop collects historical data.

Enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ntopng](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/):

> ntopng is the next generation version of the original ntop, a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does.